# How to create a action button that creates users in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have three users Admin,Reseller and Users. Now Reseller request to admin that he want XYX number of users.

This is saved in a table called **User_request** Now in admin there is a view where he can see which reseller has requested how many users.

And there is a button Approve or Reject. If Admin hits approve then I want my code to create that much users for that reseller. Now each users is mapped to his/her reseller by a field called key which is unique.

So, when users is created it must store the key of reseller in users table.

[image: Add Users]

Now, if approves users that request by re-seller must be deleted.
I am very confused what I should be doing here!

The View :

```
  <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="panel panel-info">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                      <h4>New User Requests</h4>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel-heading -->
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="dataTable_wrapper">
                            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables-example">


                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Id</th>
                                        <th>Users Requested</th>
                                        <th>Unique Id</th>
                                        <th>Date Of Request</th>
                                        <th>Approve</th>
                                        <th>Reject</th>
                                        <th>Status</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>


                               <!-- This is where we fetch all records-->

                                <tbody>

                                <?php if(count($users)): foreach($users as $user): ?>

                                    <tr class="odd gradeX">
                                        <td><?php echo  $user->id; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $user->id, $user->user_requested; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $user->id, $user->key; ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo $user->id, $user->date_requested; ?></td>
                                        <td><a href="reseller/create_user" class="btn btn-primary">Yes&nbsp<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></i></a></td>
                                        <td><a href="reseller/change_status" class="btn btn-danger">No&nbsp<?php echo'<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>';?></a></td>
                                         <td><a href="" class="btn btn-success"><?php echo  $user->status; ?></td>&nbsp</a></td>

                                    </tr>








                                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                                    <?php else: ?>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="3">We could not find any users.</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    <?php endif; ?> 



                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /.table-responsive -->

                    </div>
                    <!-- /.panel-body -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.panel -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
```

The Controller:

```
      public function create_user()
      {


        $this->load->model('more_m');

        $id = $this->session->userdata('id');

            $this->db->set('status', "'approved'",FALSE);
            $this->db->where('id',$id);
            $this->db->update('user_request');

            redirect('admin/new_user');

      }
```

Now, I just want to add the code to creates users for the requested Reseller.

Comment: can we see what youve tried so far? All youve done so far is given us a design spec.

Comment: I have set a new field called Status. Now when reseller requests users initially the status would be New when admin approves it changes to Approved and Rejected if rejects it

Comment: @DevDonkey have updated the question  please check

Comment: You need one button for creating new user, not in every row.

Comment: @Tpojka i have a button called approve if admin hits approve then i want to create number of blank rows in Users table with only reseller key inserted  i hope u get what i mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have succeeded to accomplish this :

```
      public function create_user()
      {


            $this->load->model('more_m');
            $id= $this->session->userdata('id');
            $rajan =$this->more_m->get(array('user_requested',$id));
            $request=$rajan->user_requested;        


            $this->load->model('reseller_m');

            $query=$this->db->select('key');
            $query=$this->db->get('reseller');

            if($query->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                $row = $query->row_array();
                $key= $row['key'];
            }





                    for($i=1; $i<=$request;$i++)
                        {

                        $userdata=array('key'=>$key);

                        $this->db->insert('users',$userdata);

                        }






            $this->load->model('more_m');
            $id = $this->session->userdata('id');
            $this->db->set('status', "'approved'",FALSE);
            $this->db->where('id',$id);
            $this->db->update('user_request');

            redirect('admin/new_user');

      }
```

Firstly I fetch how many users are required then the key and finally loop them and insert the users along with reseller key